# something wrong in inserting new value php

Tags: php, sql

am trying to run this code but there is something wrong for inserting the time value , i take the time value from $long am sure i write it wrong way i hope someone can give me the right way , and the time in the database is int

```
 $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $long = strtotime($now); 
 if ((isset($_GET['recordID'])) && ($_GET['recordID'] != "")) {
     $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblbills(idUser , intProduct_id , intPrice , intQuantity , time=%s)   
  SELECT tbltrolley.idUser , tbltrolley.idProduct , tbltrolley.intPrice , tbltrolley.intQuantity
  FROM tbltrolley
  WHERE tbltrolley.intOrderDone=%s AND tbltrolley.idUser=%s 
  ",
                      GetSQLValueString($long, "int"),
                       2,
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['recordID'], "int"));
```

Comment: _PLEASE_ fix your formatting.

Comment: Are both intOrderDone and idUser defined as integers in the DB?

Comment: yes it is int in the DB

Comment: sorry jhecht what formatting

Answer (score -1):

thanks everyone i just find out how to fix it , here is the code after fixing it

```js
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $long = strtotime($now); 
if ((isset($_GET['recordID'])) && ($_GET['recordID'] != "")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblbills(idUser , intProduct_id , intPrice , intQuantity , time)   
  SELECT tbltrolley.idUser , tbltrolley.idProduct , tbltrolley.intPrice , tbltrolley.intQuantity , '$long'
  FROM tbltrolley
  WHERE tbltrolley.intOrderDone=%s AND tbltrolley.idUser=%s ",
                   2,
        GetSQLValueString($_GET['recordID'], "int"));
```

Comment: If you're going to answer your own question at least explain what the problem was and how you fixed it or delete the question.

Comment: i did explain how i fix it, anyone know coding little bit can see clearly from the code where was the problem ,

Comment: You're right, I'm sure people won't need to use your solution for this type of problem because it's really easy and they wouldn't really need to come to SO to begin with.